# How to add a button to the activity of the appbar in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

this is the part that confuses me:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Startup Name Generator',
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
          tooltip: 'Open shopping cart',
          onPressed: () {
            // handle the press
          },
        ),
      ],
      home: RandomWords(),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm following the tutorial provided by google themselves, but it doesn't work:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2

I get this error:

`The argument type 'List<Widget>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<Type, Action<Intent>>?'. dart(argument_type_not_assignable)`

but the docs state that the actions property is a `List<Widget>`, so I have no clue what I did wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're working with the wrong parent Widget. The `actions` of the `MaterialApp` is not what you're looking for.

Go to your `RandomWords` Widget, make sure it builds a `Scaffold`, add an `appBar` to your `Scaffold` and set the `actions` of this `AppBar`.

You want something like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test appbar'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            tooltip: 'Open shopping cart',
            onPressed: () {
              // handle the press
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: oh my goodness, I totally misunderstood the tutorial... thank you so much man!

Comment: No worries, good luck and have fun learning! Flutter is such a great tool.